# What is causing this cryptic error message in bind_rows?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the below mentioned data frame which I am trying to bind with another data frame

```
X_df
   1  2
1 18 NA
2  3 NA
3  6 NA
4  8  8

y_df
 1  2 
35  8
```

y_df is actually the sum of each column from x. I have been trying to bind these two dataframes using bind_rows. It shows me the following error. Can I get some advice on how I can rectify it. I am relatively new to R

```
*Error in (function (cond)  : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.data.frame': Can't combine `..1$1` <table> and `..2$1` <double>*
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run using the same function `bind_rows` you've mentioned:

```
x_df
  X1 X2
1 18 NA
2  3 NA
3  6 NA
4  8  8
y_df
  X1 X2
1 35  8
x_df %>% bind_rows(y_df)
  X1 X2
1 18 NA
2  3 NA
3  6 NA
4  8  8
5 35  8
```

Another approach:

```
x_df %>% bind_rows(x_df %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(., na.rm = TRUE))))
  X1 X2
1 18 NA
2  3 NA
3  6 NA
4  8  8
5 35  8
```

Comment: my y_df does not have a row headers (1) as you did above where as x has. I think this is what's causing the issue. Any idea how I can have it rectified?

Comment: You need not use `y_df`, as you mentioned it's just column sums of the `x_df` dataframe. You can use second approach. Will that work?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to use `y_df` for totals, but use something like `janitor::adorn_totals()` for actual calculation of the columns' totals.

```
library(janitor)
library(tidyverse)
X_df %>%
  tibble::rowid_to_column() %>%
  janitor::adorn_totals(where = "row")

#    id X1 X2
#     1 18 NA
#     2  3 NA
#     3  6 NA
#     4  8  8
# Total 35  8
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `rbind` :

```
result <- rbind(X_df, y_df)
```